# How to create an Image file from dataURL and save it?

Tags: javascript, image, file, save

I have found a way to save it as PDF but now I need to save it as Image.

This is my code:

```
function downloadCert() 
    {
        html2canvas($('#canvas'), {
            
          onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            console.log(imgData);
            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, -180, -180);
            pdf.save("download.pdf");
           }
         });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const downloadFile = () => {
  const imgUri = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEA....' //Image base64 uri
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  document.body.appendChild(link)

  link.href = imgUri
  link.target = '_self'
  link.fileName = 'test_file_download.gif'
  link.download = true
  link.click()
}
```

The format in base64 string and the file extension should match for file to open properly. In above case, it's `gif`

Comment: Use link.download = 'test_file_download.gif' for file name.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function blobCallback(fileName) {
    return function(b) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = fileName+ '.jpeg';
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(b);
      a.click();
  }
}

$('#canvas').toBlob(blobCallback('DownloadFileName'), 'image/jpeg');
```